# Live updated virtual notice board

Tags: ubuntu

Is there an application that can serve this purpose:

1. Create an environment where several people can contribute, read/write
2. Give a live notification if the environment was changed
3. Handle at least 5 users

Setup, we are a tech team in a help desk looking for an application that can help us keep track of user problems for a day. So client phones in, Entry field 1: Client name, Entry Field 2: Problem Category, Entry Field 3: Resolution/Action. Notify all others that this has been changed and here are the details.

Best case scenario, this application could eventually connect to a database of clients and be able to recognize repeat problems, or repeat occurring technical queries (of a certain nature) per client.